# jquery slideToggle not working within ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I would like to use 'slideToggle()' to show/hide a set of controls. I found this code on the web and am trying to get it to work in a test application.  When I put the script within the Content control and click the button, the web site seem to run the script because the application is busy for a couple of seconds.  However, when I try to debug the javascript, I can't view it in the debugger.  When I put the script in the  section of the Site.Master page, I can see the code in the debugger but it does not run when I click the button.

This is my code in the Site.Master page:
In the  section it is as follows:

```
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">     
      <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>  
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" /> 
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
```

This is the script within the Content control:

```
<div id="body">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent">
           <script type="text/javascript">

               $(document).ready(function () {

                   var Button1 = $("[id$='_Button1']");
                   var Button2 = $("[id$='_Button2']");
                   var Panel1 = $("[id$='_Panel1']");

                   Button1.click(function (e) {

                       Panel1.slideDown();
                       e.preventDefault();
                   });

                   Button2.click(function (e) {

                       Panel1.slideUp();
                       e.preventDefault();

                   });

               });
            </script> 
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </section>
</div>
```

This is the markup on the site page:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Show Panel" />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Hide Panel" />

<br /><br />

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" Height="185px" Width="320px" style="display:none;" BackColor="#FFFF99" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">

   Hello World!

</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Using this code, the button at least looks like it is calling the script.

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Updated Code**
This script will toggle the panel although it is showing initially and I would like it to be hidden intially and also I would like the script to be run from the Site.Master page, if possible.

This is in the Default.aspx file:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=Button1.ClientID %>").click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $("#<%=Panel1.ClientID %>").slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Width="200px" Text="Show Panel" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    This is within the Panel.
</asp:Panel>
```

I add the jquery path in the Site.Master page within the  section:

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I get the script to run from Site.Master page?

Thanks.

Comment: Did....did you include jquery in your site? Open your browser console, are there any errors?

Comment: I don't have the specific version of jquery within the 'Scripts' folder in the project.  I thought having the 'src' defined would do the job.  I'm sorry for this basic question but...I don't know how to check for errors in the browser console.  How do you do that?

Comment: In all the major browsers, pressing F12 brings up the developer console.

Comment: Thanks.  I do not see any errors when I click the div control.  However, under the 'Sources' tab, it shows jquery-1.7.1.js.  This action requires 1.11.  So I just have to add this .js file to my project?

Comment: I downloaded and added the jquery 1.11.1.js file to my project under the 'Scripts' folder with the other scripts.  It is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

           $(document).ready(function () {

               $("[id$=Button1]").on("click",function (e) {

                  $("[id$=Panel1]").slideDown();
                  return false;
               });

               $("[id$=Button2]").on("click",function (e) {

                    $("[id$=Panel1]").slideUp();
                   return false;

               });

           });
        </script>
```

Comment: It still does not show Panel1.  I got the panel to show and hide when I put the script within the Content control.  But I would prefer to get the script to work in the Site.Master page because that is where I have other javascript.  I will add the updated code above.

Comment: It worked when I put it within the <head> tags.  Why doesn't it work when it is under the Content control?